# How to fix fatal error when executing setText()

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When I execute the onClick method, the app crashes. The problem seems to be in the setText funntion

I've narrowed the problem down to the given code:

There are no syntax errors in the code that were detected
Java:

```
public void calculate(View view){

        double subTotal;
        double Total;
        double tipAmount;
        TextView showTotal = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        TextView tip = findViewById(R.id.Tip);
            SeekBar percent = findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
            int percent1 = percent.getProgress() + 100;
            EditText input = findViewById(R.id.editText);
            String placeHolder = input.getText().toString();
            subTotal = Double.parseDouble(placeHolder);

            if ((subTotal >= 0) && (subTotal <= 999999) && (subTotal == (double)subTotal)){
            Total = Double.parseDouble(roundTwo.format(subTotal * percent1 * .01));
            tipAmount = Double.parseDouble(roundTwo.format(subTotal * (percent1-100) *.01));
            String totalString = Double.toString(Total);
            tip.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.Tip_Amount, tipAmount));
            showTotal.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.Total_Amount,Total));



        }
            else {
                showTotal.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.error));
            }
    }
```

Strings XML:

```
<string name="Tip_Amount">Tip: %1$d</string>
<string name="Total_Amount">Total: %1$d</string>
```

The app crashes due to the given line in the java.
Here's the Logcat data:
Logcat:

```
 Process: com.example.tipcalculator, PID: 19871
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:390)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7251)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7228)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:802)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27843)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7116)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:925)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7251) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7228) 
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:802) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27843) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7116) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:925) 
     Caused by: java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.Double
        at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:4403)
        at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printInteger(Formatter.java:2885)
        at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2839)
        at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2530)
        at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2459)
        at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2911)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:485)
        at com.example.tipcalculator.MainActivity.calculate(MainActivity.java:88)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7251) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7228) 
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:802) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27843) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7116) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:925)
```

Comment: post your `logcat/stacktrace` please

Comment: Edited, thanks in advance

Comment: could you post your activity code please? i think you may not initialized a `view` maybe one of those `tip`, `showTotal`

Comment: also you have `Caused by: java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.Double` that means some incorrect conversation. post your full code of activiy and show exactly which line of code has exception.

Comment: No I have those for sure, but I posted the method

Comment: Have you try using `<string name="Tip_Amount">Tip: %d</string>
<string name="Total_Amount">Total: %d</string>` ?

Comment: Look again. `setText()` does not appear in the stack trace. *Ergo* it is not where the problem is. The problem is earlier, in evaluating its arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used `d` in `%1$d` in the strings.xml and therefore it expects an integer. However, you are sending a double so the error occurs. Since you need decimal part, use can use `f` instead of `d` and update strings.xml as follows:

```
<string name="Tip_Amount">Tip: %1$.2f</string>
<string name="Total_Amount">Total: %1$.2f</string>
```

This way you will also get a nice representation, 2 digits after point. I recommend using BigDecimal for currencies by the way.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are passing as `tipAmount` and `Total` has type issue as your string formatter `%1$d` **is expecting int** not double or other type. First, try to print them using `Log`.

**This will work**

```
tip.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.Tip_Amount, 100));
showTotal.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.Total_Amount, 1000));
```

**This won't work**

```
tip.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.Tip_Amount, 100.00))
showTotal.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.Total_Amount, 1000.00));
```

Please, follow the link to know more about string formatting [Formatter](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Formatter)